# How is "Tai Chi Chuan" pronounced in Cantonese?

Tags: terminology, tai-chi, bruce-lee

In the ["lost interview"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk1lzkH-e4U&t=574) of Bruce Lee with Pierre Berton (1971) he says "Tai Chi Chuan" is Mandarin, but I don't fully get the Cantonese version when he tells it.

I hear "Tai te kuen" ... but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: (Any way you can think to pronounce it, [there is probably a Chinese dialect in which it is correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varieties_of_Chinese)—I've heard it said there are as many as 200.  Over 30 years I've heard it pronounced in a dozen ways:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Hanzi:** [太極拳](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%AA%E6%A5%B5%E6%8B%B3#Chinese)
- **Cantonese:** taai<sup>3</sup> gik<sup>6</sup> kyun<sup>4</sup>  <sub>(*Jyutping*)</sub>
- **[IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Cantonese):** /tʰāːi. kìk̚. kʰy̭ːn/
- **IPA:** /tʰaːi. kik̚. kʰyːn/ <sub>(without tone diacritics)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I'm cantonese
It's pronounced: Tai 'cake' kuen
Taichi chuen is mandarin

Comment: 'cake' like 'kek' or 'kejk' ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is kejk
but the "cake" ending sound of cake connects to the pronunciation of kuen

Answer (score 2):

The site mdbg has audio of native Mandarin and Cantonese speakers. See the entry for [*taijiquan*](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=taiji#). You need to click on the characters for *taijiquan* as below in the screenshot to access the audio, which is circled for Cantonese in red.

[image: mdbg.net]

Unfortunately, the middle word is missing Cantonese audio.